# How to include multiple exclusion under "Send Email Activity > Advanced Exclusions"

Tags: marketing-cloud, exclusion-script

I have an automation to send out the list of form submission in email to a list of internal contacts. The DE looks something like this:

```
Email | Campaign | Date
myself@team.com | Campaign One | 1 Jun 22
myself@team.com | Campaign Two | 10 Jun 22
other@team.com | Campaign Two | 10 Jun 22
```

I created a "Send Email Activity" and filtered out contacts from "Campaign One" under "Advanced Exclusions > Exclusion Script". However, it seems like myself@team.com was filtered out because the record is duplicated in the DE.

Question:

1. What should I do to include contacts that appeared multiple times in the DE?
2. How do I add multiple conditions? I tried using sometime like (AttributeValue("Campaign") != "Campaign One" AND AttributeValue("Date") != "1 Jun 22") but it doesn't work.

[image: Exclusion Script]

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: "Campaign != 'Campaign One'" evaluates to "true" for anyone that does not have "Campaign One" as their Campaign. Only Campaign One records would be sent to. How do multiple clauses "not work"? Your example wouldn't evaluate to true for any of your sample records.

Comment: It does not work because "myself@team.com" exist for both "Campaign One" and "Campaign Two", so when Exclusion script excluded the record != "Campaign One", it somehow remove the same record from "Campaign Two".

Comment: Have you tried removing deduplication of subscribers for the send? My guess is deduplication's happening before the exclusion's applied, so maybe you're just left with the first record that's excluded.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to prevent sends to anyone that has a Campaign value of "Campaign One" or if they have multiple entries in the DE, then you could do something like this in your Exclusion Script:

```
AttributeValue("Campaign") == "Campaign One" 
OR rowcount(lookuprows("YOURDENAME","Email", AttributeValue("emailaddr"))) > 1
```

Since negative logic is confusing, I always use this mnemonic preceding my exclusion script conditional:

> Exclude the send to this subscriber if ___ is true

Reference:

- [LookupRows](https://ampscript.guide/lookuprows)
- [RowCount](https://ampscrit.guide/rowcount)

**20220627 UPDATE**

You can test exclusion script logic in your email by like this:

```ampscript
%%[

if AttributeValue("Campaign") == "Campaign One" 
   OR rowcount(lookuprows("YOURDENAME","Email", AttributeValue("emailaddr"))) > 1 then
  set @excluded = "true"
else
  set @excluded = "false"
endif

output(concat("<br>excluded: ", @excluded))

]%%
```

Once you've achieved the desired results, move what's between the `if` and `then` to your Exclusion Script.

Comment: If I use this logic, then it'll exclude contacts with "Campaign One", which is not the intent since this is "Exclusion Script", right?

Comment: I'm just providing an approach.  I'll leave the criteria up to you.  I've updated my answer with an example for testing in the email -- outside of the send definition.  I find it easier to start there.